# Staging build config - production code with development database

Tags: vuejs2, webpack-4

How do I configure webpack in vue to produce a production code/build but using a development config?

I have the following two npm scripts:

```
"build": "vue-cli-service build",
"build-dev": "vue-cli-service build --mode development",
```

And two config files:

```
.env.production
.env.development
```

Now I need to deploy the code to the development server and make sure the code is absolutely the same as in production so I can test it properly first, but I need to use the dev database for that.

Any thoughts on how to make webpack to create a production code with the `mode` set to anything else rather than production?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was just a matter of overriding `NODE_ENV=production` in the `.env` config file.

So something like this solved the problem:

```
# .env.staging
NODE_ENV=production
OTHER_VARS=...
```

And a script:

```
"build-stage": "vue-cli-service build --mode staging",
```